# Optimization with inequality constraints using R

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, rstudio, lpsolve

I am trying to minimize the function:

```
f(x) = -x[1]*x[2]*x[3]
```

subject to the constraints:

```
0 <= x[1] + 2*x[2] + 2*x[3] <= 72.
```

What I did so far is that I wrote the constraint as two separate constraints:

```
constraint_1: -x[1] - 2*x[2] - 2*x[3] <=0
constraint_2: x[1] + 2*x[2] + 2*x[3] <= 72
```

Then I used the following codes, however I cannot figure out what I should write for the objective.in:

```
library(lpSolve)
lp(direction = "min", objective.in, const.mat, const.dir, const.rhs)
const.mat = matrix(c(-1,-2,-2,1,2,2), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow=TRUE)
constraint_1 = 0
constraint_2 = 72
const.rhs = c(constraint_1, constraint_2)
const.dir = c("<=", "<=")
```

EDIT:

I used nloptr package, but I am having this error: "Error in .checkfunargs(eval_f, arglist, "eval_f") :

eval_f requires argument 'x_2' but this has not been passed to the 'nloptr' function."

When I apply these codes:

## objective function

eval_f0 <-function( x_1, x_2, x_3 ){

return(-x_1*x_2*x_3)

}

eval_grad_f0 <-function( x_1, x_2, x_3 ){

return(c(-x_2*x_3, -x_1*x_3, -x_1*x_2))

}

## constraint function

eval_g0 <- function(x_1, x_2, x_3) {

return((-x_1 - 2*x_2 - 2*x_3),

(x_1 + 2*x_2 + 2*x_3 - 72))

}

eval_jac_g0 <- function(x_1, x_2, x_3) {

return(rbind(c(-1,-2,-2),

c(1,2,2)))

}

res0 <-nloptr(x0=c(0,0,0),

eval_f=eval_f0,

eval_grad_f=eval_grad_f0,

lb =c(-Inf,-Inf,-Inf),

ub =c(Inf,Inf,Inf),

eval_g_ineq =eval_g0,

eval_jac_g_ineq =eval_jac_g0,

opts =list("algorithm"="NLOPT_LD_MMA",

"xtol_rel"=1.0e-8,

"print_level"=3,

"check_derivatives"=TRUE,

"check_derivatives_print"="all"))

Comment: Linear programming requires a linear objective and linear constraints. lpSolve cannot be used for nonlinear problems.

Comment: Thank you. How can I solve this nonlinear problem then?

Comment: Also, even if I convert it to a linear function by taking the log, still I do not know how to write the objective.in values since there isn't any numerical vector of coefficients.

Comment: Try the `nloptr` package.

Comment: I did, but it gives me this error:  "Error in .checkfunargs(eval_f, arglist, "eval_f") :

eval_f requires argument 'x_2' but this has not been passed to the 'nloptr' function."